# Is there a way to make a Regex pattern where a specific OR operator must match another OR operator?

Tags: swift, regex

Basically I have a simple HTML file, here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Text</p>
    <h2>Text H2</h2>
    <p>Text 1</p>
    <h3>Text H3</h3>

</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is get the text between the HTML tags, I only want to get the text between specific tags like `<p>`, `<h3>` etc..

This is the Regex pattern I'm currently using:

```
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern:"<p>(.*?)</p>", options: [])
```

This code works perfectly fine but only returns the text between the p tags, when I do the following:

```
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern:"<(p|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6)>(.*?)</(p|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6)>", options: [])
```

This doesn't work, it's only returning the actual tags like p, h1, h2 without the arrows "<", ">". It should return the text between the tags.

I'm not sure what's causing this to happen, are the parentheses the problem or the pattern is off completely?!

Comment: Doesn't the opening tag name supposed to match the closing tag name ? `<(p|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6)>(.*?)</\1>` where group 1 is the tag name, group 2 is the content between open/close ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every match between `(` and `)` is a capture group unless you use `?:`:

```
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern:"<(?:p|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6)>(.*?)</(?:p|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6)>", options: [])
```